# Visual Studio for Mac 2022 Preview Change Shortcuts

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2022

Because of the M1 native support i started using Visual Studio 2022 Preview 5 (build 6509). The only problem i have is that i can't change my keyboard shortcuts. I can change the scheme but not any command separate. I have tried to use the Visual Studio Code scheme because on my instance of Visual Studio Code every shortcut is set correct (for me ;)).

Is there some sort of workaround to edit the keyboard shortcuts?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, my workaround was to install the Visual Studio 2019 on my M1 MacBook and edit the shortcuts on the "old" version, seems like they share same .properties file.